# inkscape command line, where is it on mac?

Tags: macos, inkscape

This is a kinda silly question. I've installed Inkscape on my mac (Marvericks OS) following this page http://www.inkscape.org/en/download/mac-os/

I know there is a command line option with inkscape. I tried to type inkscape on Terminal and there is no such command. I'm confused... Does this mean that I need to install the linux version of inkscape in order to use the command line?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I have Inkscape installed in `/Applications` and running this from a terminal does the trick:

```
/Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/MacOS/inkscape --help

Usage: inkscape-bin [OPTIONS...] [FILE...]

Available options:
  -V, --version                             Print the Inkscape version number

... etc.
```

For ease of use symlink it to `/usr/local/bin` i.e.:

```
ln -s /Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/MacOS/inkscape \
      /usr/local/bin/inkscape
```

In general, on MacOS Inkscape needs to be called with an absolute path, and all files given as arguments should also be full paths. See also:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1449251

Comment: I've tried this and it opened up the program... not something i want to do.

Comment: This worked! But there are a lot error messages with other things. Another question, do I need to put this path in PATH to be able to invoke inkscape directly?

Comment: adding `/Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/Resources/bin/` to your path should let you run `inkscape -?`.  The error messages can probably be ignored - not certain but I think they aren't as critical as they claim and actually occur when you run the app normally but you can't see them.

Comment: You can add a shortcut to the normal location for such things.
  
`ln -s /Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/Resources/bin/inkscape /usr/local/bin/inkscape`
  
This creates a symbolic link for inkscape to a folder already in the standard path

Comment: It should (now) be `/Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/Resources/bin/inkscape-bin`  - I've updated the answer to fix.

Comment: inkscape-bin didn't work for me. then i found http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/MacOS_X, which says that an alias should be used `alias inkscape="/Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/Resources/bin/inkscape"`

Comment: As of 2020, the location on the command line app is now `/Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/MacOS/inkscape`.

Answer (score 38):

As of 2020, the executable on MacOS is now located at

```
/Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/MacOS/inkscape
```

You can symlink it with:

```
ln -s /Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/MacOS/inkscape \
  /usr/local/bin/inkscape
```

More info about command line usage [here](https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php?title=Using_the_Command_Line).

Comment: When I create this symlink then try to use it I get the following error:

`/usr/local/bin/inkscape: line 196: /usr/Contents/MacOS/inkscape-bin: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/inkscape: line 196: exec: /usr/Contents/MacOS/inkscape-bin: cannot execute: No such file or directory`

Any ideas?

Comment: @colmjude don't type the "\" backslash in the command line.

Answer (score 3):

I think some paths and filenames have changed over time and today you should add a symlink in `/usr/local/bin` to point to the bin directory of inkscape:

`sudo ln -s /Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/Resources/bin/inkscape /usr/local/bin/inkscape`

Full credit to @Scott above who has this correct "answer" showing as a comment.  This solution allows other subcommands of inkscape to work correctly, whereas creating an alias does not.