# Using inkscape in mac command line

Tags: macos, shell, inkscape

When I set symlink `ln -s /Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/Resources/bin/inkscape-bin /usr/local/bin/inkscape` on MacOS El Capitan and try run Inkscape using it gives me a plenty of errors (see below). Where is the problem, please? I need it for grunt-rasterize. When I use alias as suggested on Inkscape webpage it works but grunt is not able to run Inkscape via alias.

```
** (process:1318): WARNING **: Units file Contents/Resources/share/inkscape/ui/units.xml is missing: Failed to open file 'Contents/Resources/share/inkscape/ui/units.xml': No such file or directory



(process:1318): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.

Using the fallback 'C' locale.


(inkscape:1318): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Cannot open pixbuf loader module file '/Users/liam/mp-x11/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache': No such file or directory


This likely means that your installation is broken.

Try running the command

  gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders > /Users/liam/mp-x11/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache

to make things work again for the time being.


** (inkscape:1318): WARNING **: Unable to open PowerPoint fontfix file: Contents/Resources/share/inkscape/extensions/fontfix.conf

PowerPoint ungrouping compensation in WMF/EMF export will not be available.


** (inkscape:1318): WARNING **: Can't open file: Contents/Resources/share/inkscape/keys/default.xml (doesn't exist)


** (inkscape:1318): WARNING **: Unable to read keys file Contents/Resources/share/inkscape/keys/default.xml


(inkscape:1318): Pango-CRITICAL **: No modules found:

No builtin or dynamically loaded modules were found.

PangoFc will not work correctly.

This probably means there was an error in the creation of:

  '/Users/liam/mp-x11/etc/pango/pango.modules'

You should create this file by running:

  pango-querymodules > '/Users/liam/mp-x11/etc/pango/pango.modules'


(inkscape:1318): Pango-WARNING **: failed to choose a font, expect ugly output. engine-type='PangoRenderCoreText', script='common'


(inkscape:1318): Gtk-WARNING **: Could not find the icon 'object-visible'. The 'hicolor' theme

was not found either, perhaps you need to install it.

You can get a copy from:

http://icon-theme.freedesktop.org/releases


(inkscape:1318): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Error loading XPM image loader: Image type 'xpm' is not supported


(inkscape:1318): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Error loading XPM image loader: Image type 'xpm' is not supported


(inkscape:1318): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Error loading XPM image loader: Image type 'xpm' is not supported


(inkscape:1318): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_read_pixels: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed


Emergency save activated!

Emergency save completed. Inkscape will close now.

If you can reproduce this crash, please file a bug at www.inkscape.org

with a detailed description of the steps leading to the crash, so we can fix it.


(inkscape:1318): Pango-WARNING **: failed to choose a font, expect ugly output. engine-type='PangoRenderCoreText', script='latin'

Segmentation fault: 11`
```

Comment: Are you running it from actual shell?  Also, you could always build a trivial sciprt `#!/bin/sh\n/path/to/inkscape $@` instead of a symlink

Comment: look at the second answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22085168/inkscape-command-line-where-is-it-on-mac
they suggest calling a different executable